# Control access in JSF files

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, authentication

I'm working on a JSF project, and it has a `login.xhtml` file, which a user login and go to a different page by his role.

Actually, I have four roles:

- Administrator
- Counter
- Client
- Cashier

Associated with four home pages:

- indexAdministrator.xhtml
- indexCounter.xhtml
- indexClient.xhtml
- indexCashier.xhtml

That's working allright, but the problem is when a user that isn't login. Go to `page.xhtml` directly from the URL, it enters, and I need only the users authorized do that.

If it's something, I have two arguments in the Httpsession:

```
session.setAttribute("currentUser", currentUser);
session.setAttribute("role", role);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the info you gave, I'd say your .xhtml pages aren't checking if the user has permissions to see them. Put a check and redirect all who are not authorized.